# How do I stream incomplete data csv data from a Serial device using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, arduino, raspberry-pi, serial-port, streaming

I have a simple Arduino sketch that looks like this (please ignore the blocking delay for now)...

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
    Serial.println("Hello world from Ardunio!\n");
    delay(5000);
}
```

This works great so I created a node library to communicate with the serial port...

```
import SerialPort from 'serialport';
import parse from 'csv-parse';

const output=[];
const parser = parse({
  to_line: 10
});

const port = new SerialPort('/dev/ttyACM0', {
  baudRate: 115200
});

port.on('readable', function () {
  let record
  while (record = port.read()) {
    output.push(record.toString());
    console.log(`The collection is \n ${JSON.stringify(output)}`);
  }
})
port.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('Error: ', err.message);
});
port.on('close', function(){
  console.log('The port is closed');
});
port.on('open', err =>{
  console.log("The port is opened");
});
```

My expectation is that this would read 10 lines and stop. However, when it runs I see records like this...

```
The collection is 
 ["d from Ardunio!\n\r\n"]
The collection is 
 ["d from Ardunio!\n\r\n","Hello world from Ardu"]
The collection is 
 ["d from Ardunio!\n\r\n","Hello world from Ardu","nio!\n\r\n"]
```

This of course isn't right because the buffer is only reading pieces of each record at a time. What is the best way (library or roll my own) to handle these records and combine the strings until the new line (or comma if multiple columns)?

Comment: Why should it read 10 lines and then stop ? And what are you trying to create ?

Comment: When you using `port.on("Readable")`, you are operate in pause mode. Please read the SerialPort API [documentation](https://serialport.io/docs/guide-usage#reading-data) for better understanding of the library. Particularly about [readline parser](https://serialport.io/docs/api-parser-readline) that might be what you are looking for.